# How to use WEEKNUM in big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Big Query SQL and I can't use a couple of functions and more specifically WEEKNUM. Everytime I try to, it outputs unrecognized function.

[WEEKNUM](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/WEEKNUM-Function_118228789)

During my search I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Derive-Transform_57344634#example---other-examples) that I think it meansI can't use `derive` functions, and I also think that part of it is the WEEKNUM. I could be totally wrong though.

So how can I use the WEEKNUM function or do what it does with another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Standard SQL, use [`EXTRACT()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract):

```
select extract(week from current_date)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Any ideas on why I can't use WEEKNUM?

Comment: @Lev . . . It is not a BigQuery function.  `EXTRACT()` is the standard SQL function to retrieve this information, so it is quite appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Your link to [WEEKNUM](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/WEEKNUM-Function_118228789) is for Google Cloud DataPrep.  The [BigQuery Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions) for date functions does not use `WEEKNUM`, but allows similar functionality through `EXTRACT` or `FORMAT_DATE`.